# How To Send Request Authorization Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: angular, authorization, httprequest, token

> Hi every body. I want to request to get token. But it not working

## My Code Angular 7

```
const url = "http://localhost:50729/token", body = 'username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password';
const requestHeader = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
this.http.post(url, body, { headers: requestHeader }).toPromise().then(res => {
  //result
  console.log(res.json());
}).catch(x => alert("Username Or PassWord Incorrect!"));
```

> Where is Wrong? How to make it working! Thank all you!

Answer (score 0):

First point is that if you are using HttpClient from '@angular/common/http' you don't have to do `res.json()` as it doesn't needed anymore (since angular v4.3 I guess)

Second point is that you are probably trying to send `FormData`. Try:

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('username', 'admin')
body.append('password', 'admin')
body.append('grant_type', 'password')
```

Third point is trying to set the `Content-Type` to `undefined` to let HttpClient automatically set the headers depending on body argument.

That should be it.